# DataContractSerializer - How to serialize objects using ElementName instead of property name?

Tags: c#, xml, datacontractserializer

I'm facing serialization issue while using `DataContractSerializer`. The issue I'm facing is that the generated XML file always have the tags with names defined for the class and fields instead of the names set in `XmlRoot` or `XmlElement` using `ElementName` attribute. e.g. For the class defined as follows:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

The generated XML in my case is always:

```
<Customer>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Address>xyz</Address>
</Customer>
```

while the output I'm looking to get is the one using `ElementName` in lowercase:

```
<customer>
    <name>abc</name>
    <address>xyz</address>
</customer>
```

I'm using an extension method to serialize by C# object using the following:

```
public static XDocument SerializeToXElement(object o)
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument();

    using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(o.GetType());
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, o);
    }

    doc.StripNamespace();

    return doc;
}
```

I also have another extension method being called in my serialize function to strip the namespaces out from my `XDocument`, which is as follows:

```
public static void StripNamespace(this XDocument document)
{
    if (document.Root == null) return;

    foreach (var element in document.Root.DescendantsAndSelf())
    {
        element.Name = element.Name.LocalName;
        element.ReplaceAttributes(GetAttributesWithoutNamespace(element));
    }
}
```

What can I do to make the DataContractSerializer use `ElementName` instead of the  class/property names?

Comment: Maybe you should use DataContract and DataMember attributes? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The code posted should work.  Are you sure you are running the latest version of the executable?  I would check the project bin folder and see if the latest version by the date is in the debug or release folder and then make sure you are running the latest version.

Comment: @jdweng I've deleted the whole publish folder and republished, so should be using the latest code.

Comment: @SJaka Remove one of the attribute and see if you still get the latest results, that would means you are 100% using latest code

Comment: @MuhammadRaja - Yes, it does. Already checked.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the first comment suggested? The `DataContractSerializer` does not look at `XmlElement`, `XmlRoot` etc, only the `XmlSerializer` does.

Comment: @RuiJarimba - I was using XmlSerializer earlier, which I changed to DataContractSerializer later for some other requirements, but didn't change the class decorations. Changing to DataContract/DataMember fixed the issue.  - If you post that as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @SJaka added my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you should [use DataContract and DataMember attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `XmlRoot` and `XmlElement`:

```
[DataContract(Name = "customer", Namespace = "")]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you,

```
[XmlRoot("customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nope. It didn't. Still the same result as before. I believe `XmlRoot(string)` is defining the `ElementName` anyways.